# Export tags ONLY from evernote?

Tags: applescript, evernote

I found this: [Using Applescript to export list of URLs based on tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696649/using-applescript-to-export-list-of-urls-based-on-tags), which was a great resource. The original script (from Veritrope) is a little old, but worked great for exporting Evernote note titles. I thought it would be relatively easy to modify this script to get JUST the tags in my notebooks into CSV. But since I'm very much an amateur at scripting, and self-taught at that, I couldn't make it work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My ultimate aim is to do some tag maintenance, because I now have so many tags that they're not very helpful any more. So I'd just like a list of tags - does NOT have to be associated to the notes. One column of data.

Thanks, stackies.

Comment: can someone explain why this was down voted? this, and my last question, were both panned w/o any explanation. this community seems to be getting more intolerant; i don't get it. i'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Your question was downvoted because you did not ask for a specific answer to a specific question.  Questions of the form "How do I do X?" or "Can you point me in the right direction?" generally do not go so well on StackOverflow.   You are expected to do research and try your best to find a solution on your own before asking a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks. boy, this community is tough to figure out!! i actually did do a ton of research on this, and even tried to adapt scripts i found myself. i guess i just didn't ask the right way. "phrasing, Lana." anyway, thanks for the script below, too. going to try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an AppleScript program that will do what you wish to do:

```
tell application "Evernote"
    set tagList to {}
    set allNotebooks to every notebook
    repeat with currentNotebook in allNotebooks
        set allNotes to every note in currentNotebook
        repeat with currentNote in allNotes
            set noteTags to (the tags of currentNote)
            repeat with currentTag in noteTags
                if tagList does not contain name of currentTag then
                    set the end of tagList to name of currentTag

                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "Evernote Tags.csv"
set output to ""
repeat with currentTag in tagList
    set output to output & currentTag & ", "
end repeat

set theResult to writeTo(filePath, output, text, false)
if not theResult then display dialog "There was an error writing the data!"

on writeTo(targetFile, theData, dataType, apendData)
    -- targetFile is the path to the file you want to write
    -- theData is the data you want in the file.
    -- dataType is the data type of theData and it can be text, list, record etc.
    -- apendData is true to append theData to the end of the current contents of the file or false to overwrite it
    try
        set targetFile to targetFile as text
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if apendData is false then set eof of openFile to 0
        write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType
        close access openFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeTo
```